# How to pass payload of an action to another rxjs operator in redux-observable?

Tags: electron, rxjs6, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable with rxjs's tap operator to initialize an ipcRenderer event. Before of that I want to dispatch another action. The question is how to proper pass the payload to the tap operator? -

Note: I want to keep the tap operator at the end of sequence

I have tried to pass it in the action's payload but It is not what I want.. check the example

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import { map, tap, ignoreElements } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';

import { togglePackageLoader } from 'models/ui/actions'
import { viewPackageStart} from '../actions';

// I want to pass payload to tap
/* togglePackageLoader returns {  
  type: 'TOGGLE_LOADER',
  payload: {
    loading: true,
    options: {
      opt1: value1,
    }
  }
}

// i want to avoid passing options to toggleLoader payload..
*/
const viewPackageEpic = pipe(
    ofType(viewPackageStart.type),
    map(({ payload }) => togglePackageLoader({
        loading: true,
        options: payload
    })),
    tap(({ payload: { options } }) => {
        ipcRenderer.send('npm-view', options)
    }),
    ignoreElements()
);

export { viewPackageEpic };
```

I expected to dispatch toggleLoader first then make the ipcRenderer call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that suits my needs. I created another epic which catch the same type. Using ignoreElements after the tap operatator.

```
const viewPackageEpic = pipe(
    ofType(viewPackageStart.type),
    map(() => updatePackageLoader({
        loading: true
    })),
);

const viewPackageLoaderEpic = pipe(
    ofType(viewPackageStart.type),
    tap(({ payload: { options } }) => {
        ipcRenderer.send('npm-view', options)
    }),
    ignoreElements()
);
```